# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...productsCtg.map...') react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tried to display products to a screen and what i get is that error,here is my code:

```
{productsCtg.length > 0 ? (
   <View style={styles.listContainer}>
       {productsCtg.map((item) => {
         console.log(item);
           return(
               <ProductList
                   navigation={props.navigation}
                   key={item.id}
                   item={item}
               />
           );
       })}
   </View>
   ) : (
       <View style={[styles.center, { height: height / 2}]}>
           <Text style={{fontFamily: 'nunito_semi_bold'}}>No products found</Text>
       </View>
   )}
```

And i fetch data from an api using useFocusEffect and useCallBack and axios,when app starts products shows but when i try to save any file in the project without making any changes that error appears and when i save again products show up again, i need help and here is another codes:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
const [productsFiltered, setProductsFiltered] = useState([]);
const [focus, setFocus] = useState();
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
const [productsCtg, setProductsCtg] = useState([]);
const [active, setActive] = useState();
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useFocusEffect((
useCallback(
  () => {
    setFocus(false);
    setActive(-1);
    
    // Products
    axios
      .get(`${baseURL}products`)
      .then((res) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
        setProductsFiltered(res.data);
        setProductsCtg(res.data);
        setInitialState(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
        //console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Api call error')
      })

    //Categories
    axios
      .get(`${baseURL}categories`)
      .then((res) => {
        setCategories(res.data);
        //console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Api call error')
      })

    return () => {
      setProducts([]);
      setProductsFiltered([]);
      setFocus();
      setCategories([]);
      setActive();
      setInitialState();
      // setProductsCtg([]);
    };
  },
  [],
)
```

))

---

when i console.log before return() the first five arrays are empty and the rest contains repeated data, each array contains six products(objects),and and when i console.log inside a map function all the arrays have repeated data like below(but all),the output of console.log is:

```
Array []
Array []
Array []
Array []
Array []
Array [
Object {
"brand": "Arusha",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 45,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-04T06:32:06.300Z",
"description": "Mtama mzuri sana kutoka arusha",
"id": "629afc66e400878b161e437b",
"image": "http://2fa0-197-250-230- 
109.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/21fe5b14-3eee-4218-b554-9a3d17bd801b.jpg- 
1654333522641.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Mtama",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 42000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Dodoma",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 27,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-04T08:59:36.678Z",
"description": "Good quality maize in Dodoma,place your order now.",
"id": "629b1ef89e9b9401aba2ba54",
"image": "http://2fa0-197-250-230- 
109.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/fffe96ff-4558-42db-a6b4-7b5b289995be.jpg- 
1654333175940.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Maize",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 76000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Mbeya",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 16,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:04:19.040Z",
"description": "Mchele mzuri kutoka mbeya,weka oda yako sasa",
"id": "629c7fa3342fe22635019648",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/8c107f75-31e0-4a6c-9835-27a8f6ada063.jpg- 
1654423458901.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Rice",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 80000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Tanga",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 12,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:39:52.196Z",
"description": "Quality beans available,place your order anytime",
"id": "629c87f8499c526723a96979",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/291ee0f1-369e-45a1-8b43-38756c0d866b.jpg- 
1654425591386.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Beans",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 85000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Kilimanjaro",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 12,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:43:04.778Z",
"description": "Karibu upate ndizi kubwa na zenye ubora wa hali ya 
juu,weka oda yako sasa",
"id": "629c88b8499c526723a9698c",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/4e10f2a7-9ee0-4735-bd8b-75b1af2d48e4.jpg- 
1654425784444.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Ndizi",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 31500,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Dar es salaam",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 133,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:47:48.391Z",
"description": "Tunauza mahindi kwa jumla,weka oda yako mapema,karibu 
sana",
"id": "629c89d4499c526723a969a5",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/6895e399-6254-4c46-a757-2d10a0b188b2.jpg- 
1654426067682.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Maize",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 73500,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
]
Array [
Object {
"brand": "Arusha",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 45,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-04T06:32:06.300Z",
"description": "Mtama mzuri sana kutoka arusha",
"id": "629afc66e400878b161e437b",
"image": "http://2fa0-197-250-230- 
109.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/21fe5b14-3eee-4218-b554-9a3d17bd801b.jpg- 
1654333522641.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Mtama",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 42000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Dodoma",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 27,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-04T08:59:36.678Z",
"description": "Good quality maize in Dodoma,place your order now.",
"id": "629b1ef89e9b9401aba2ba54",
"image": "http://2fa0-197-250-230- 
109.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/fffe96ff-4558-42db-a6b4-7b5b289995be.jpg- 
1654333175940.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Maize",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 76000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Mbeya",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 16,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:04:19.040Z",
"description": "Mchele mzuri kutoka mbeya,weka oda yako sasa",
"id": "629c7fa3342fe22635019648",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/8c107f75-31e0-4a6c-9835-27a8f6ada063.jpg- 
1654423458901.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Rice",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 80000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Tanga",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 12,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:39:52.196Z",
"description": "Quality beans available,place your order anytime",
"id": "629c87f8499c526723a96979",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/291ee0f1-369e-45a1-8b43-38756c0d866b.jpg- 
1654425591386.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Beans",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 85000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Kilimanjaro",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 12,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:43:04.778Z",
"description": "Karibu upate ndizi kubwa na zenye ubora wa hali ya 
juu,weka oda yako sasa",
"id": "629c88b8499c526723a9698c",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/4e10f2a7-9ee0-4735-bd8b-75b1af2d48e4.jpg- 
1654425784444.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Ndizi",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 31500,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Dar es salaam",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 133,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:47:48.391Z",
"description": "Tunauza mahindi kwa jumla,weka oda yako mapema,karibu 
sana",
"id": "629c89d4499c526723a969a5",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/6895e399-6254-4c46-a757-2d10a0b188b2.jpg- 
1654426067682.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Maize",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 73500,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
]
Array [
Object {
"brand": "Arusha",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 45,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-04T06:32:06.300Z",
"description": "Mtama mzuri sana kutoka arusha",
"id": "629afc66e400878b161e437b",
"image": "http://2fa0-197-250-230- 
109.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/21fe5b14-3eee-4218-b554-9a3d17bd801b.jpg- 
1654333522641.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Mtama",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 42000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Dodoma",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 27,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-04T08:59:36.678Z",
"description": "Good quality maize in Dodoma,place your order now.",
"id": "629b1ef89e9b9401aba2ba54",
"image": "http://2fa0-197-250-230- 
109.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/fffe96ff-4558-42db-a6b4-7b5b289995be.jpg- 
1654333175940.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Maize",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 76000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Mbeya",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 16,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:04:19.040Z",
"description": "Mchele mzuri kutoka mbeya,weka oda yako sasa",
"id": "629c7fa3342fe22635019648",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/8c107f75-31e0-4a6c-9835-27a8f6ada063.jpg- 
1654423458901.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Rice",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 80000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Tanga",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 12,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:39:52.196Z",
"description": "Quality beans available,place your order anytime",
"id": "629c87f8499c526723a96979",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/291ee0f1-369e-45a1-8b43-38756c0d866b.jpg- 
1654425591386.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Beans",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 85000,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Kilimanjaro",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 12,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:43:04.778Z",
"description": "Karibu upate ndizi kubwa na zenye ubora wa hali ya 
juu,weka oda yako sasa",
"id": "629c88b8499c526723a9698c",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/4e10f2a7-9ee0-4735-bd8b-75b1af2d48e4.jpg- 
1654425784444.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Ndizi",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 31500,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
Object {
"brand": "Dar es salaam",
"category": Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "62925a7db9e8b1361367c733",
  "color": null,
  "icon": null,
  "name": "food crops",
},
"countInStock": 133,
"dateCreated": "2022-06-05T10:47:48.391Z",
"description": "Tunauza mahindi kwa jumla,weka oda yako mapema,karibu 
sana",
"id": "629c89d4499c526723a969a5",
"image": "http://1063-197-250-224- 
205.eu.ngrok.io/public/uploads/6895e399-6254-4c46-a757-2d10a0b188b2.jpg- 
1654426067682.jpeg",
"images": Array [],
"isFeatured": false,
"name": "Maize",
"numReviews": 0,
"price": 73500,
"rating": 0,
"richDescription": "undefined",
},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

check type of productsCtg if it is Object;

This error means productsCtg is not a array
Try:

```
console.log(productsCtg)
```

Comment: when i console.log t's an array as output is "Array []" when empty but once data is loaded the output of console.log is the array that is repeated three times with the same data,i don't why,it could be useCallBack or? any idea?

Comment: Can you show the array repeted three time

Comment: yes,i it's not three time,now it's seven times i think